# A physical basis for Heisenberg ferromagnetic cluster model

Tags: quantum-spin, spin-chains

Consider the following situation. There are $N$ spins 1/2 (for example 1/2, it may be any other value $s$) and they interact via the Hamiltonian:
$$\hat{H}=-\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{J}{N}\hat{\vec{S}}_i \hat{\vec{S}}_j$$
Here indecies $i$ and $j$ run over the whole range from 1 to $N$. The coupling constant is the same for any pair of spins.

Thus, this Hamiltonian describes the following case: there are a lot of spins and each one of them interacts with each other with the same force. This model is a kind of an antipod of the closest neighbor model, the other limiting case - absolutly uniform interaction.

As I've heard, this model is refered to as *Heisenberg cluster model*.

**My question is as follows:** what is the physics that may lay behind this model? Is there any experimental situation, that can be described, using this "uniform" Hamiltonian? Maybe it can describe some kind of small ferromagnetic granules? Any suggestions or actual links are welcomed.

In this model one can calculate *exactly* a lot of interesting things: thermal capacity, magnetisation, entropy and so on, so I'm really interested whether one can draw any parallels with acual experimental situaton.

I would be greatful, if you could give me some links to papers that examine this matter.

Thank you in advance.